# Is there a way to get the connection string out of sqlalchemy in log suitable format?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I want to log the database connection, but don't want to show the password (or the driver/dialect).

Is there a way to get this out of SQLAlchemy or should I just resort to regex parsing? SQLAlchemy should have already parsed it to find this out so it seems silly to do it myself, but I can't find anything on http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html or http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `URL.__repr__` method hides the password:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/test')

assert repr(engine.url) == 'postgresql://scott:***@localhost/test'
```

If you want to hide the driver/dialect, you may wish to look at how the URL class computes a string in [`URL.__to_string__`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/6e1f34ed6230d7fce338ee4fb022678a7e511627/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py#L66).

Answer (score 3):

Using `repr(engine)` will include the class name. To get just the URL representation do:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/test')

assert repr(engine.url) == 'postgresql://scott:***@localhost/test'
```

(note that `.url` is the only addition)

Comment: It would have been better to comment or propose an edit to fix the mistake that was in my answer.